# Can Archon Beam Shoot Through Wall?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Archon beam is the right click stuff when you turned into archon as wizard.

It definitely can when the wall is created by the monster.

When it's a regular wall, the result is not clear. I can't see the monster. Sometimes I can't see the numbers popping out, either.

I mean can anyone confirm this with reference?

Note: Archon beam can also attack across ladders, etc.

Comment: you should be able to check by seeing if your archon duration changes, can't you?

Comment: Ah a good idea. Usually I shoot through walls if I am attacking rare. The other die so quickly. So won't be easy too.

Answer (score 2):

No, the archon beam cannot shoot through walls.  The only wall it can shoot through are the barriers put up by the waller elites.